# How to assign GDI+ POINT Class address from memory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, gdi+

In C++ I would like to use function Polyline (hdc, apt, cpt) from prepared point pairs x, y but I need to assign memory address in

```
POINT apt[156];
```

as I have point pairs stored in RAM (DWORD) including the number of pairs (DWORD) by assembler function call. How to assign to POINT GDI+ structure apt address and number of point pairs in square brackets?

Answer (score 2):

As input, [`Polyline()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polyline) takes a pointer to an array of [`POINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805.aspx) structs, and the number of elements in the array.

`POINT` has two data members that are both of type `LONG`, so if you have an existing array of `DWORD` pairs in memory, you could simply type-cast that address to a `POINT*` pointer when you pass it to `Polyline()` (as `DWORD` and `LONG` have the same byte size in the Win32 API), eg:

```
DWORD *pairs = ...;
DWORD numPairs = ...;
...    
Polyline(hdc, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(pairs), numPairs);
```

However, a safer approach is to simply allocate a separate `POINT[]` array in memory and copy the `DWORD` values into it, then pass that array to `Polyline()`, eg:

```
DWORD *pairs = ...;
DWORD numPairs = ...;
...    

POINT *points = new POINT[numPairs];
for(DWORD i = 0; i < numPairs; ++i)
{
    points[i].x = pairs[i*2];
    points[i].y = pairs[(i*2)+1];
}

Polyline(hdc, points, numPairs);

delete[] points;
```

FYI, in your question you mention GDI+, but `Polyline()` is part of GDI, not GDI+.  The GDI+ equivilent is [`Graphics::DrawLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawlines(inconstpen_inconstpoint_inint)), but it requires an array of [`Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/gdiplustypes/nl-gdiplustypes-point) class objects instead of `POINT` structs.  You can't safely type-cast a `DWORD` array to `Point*`, you would have to actually construct the individual `Point` objects (using the [`Point(int,int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms535011.aspx) constructor), similar to above, eg:

```
DWORD *pairs = ...;
DWORD numPairs = ...;
...    

Point *points = new Point[numPairs];
for(DWORD i = 0; i < numPairs; ++i)
    points[i] = Point(static_cast<INT>(pairs[i*2]), static_cast<INT>(pairs[(i*2)+1]));

Graphics *g = Graphics::FromHDC(hdc);
Pen pen(...);
g->DrawLines(&pen, points, numPairs);
delete g;

delete[] points;
```

Comment: I allocate the memory by:

`BYTE* ptr = static_cast<BYTE*>(VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
BYTE* pairs = ptr;`

read the data into memory and process them by ASM fucntion call. Unfortunately

`Polyline(hdc, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(pairs), numPairs);`

doesn't work. When I hover the mouse over POINT* I don't see any data pairs and Polyline function does nothing.

Comment: @Ziggi then you are not populating the allocated memory with data that resembles `POINT` structs. So what are you populating it with exactly ?

Comment: Memory contains x, y pairs as DWORD:
d5 05 00 00 24 02 00 00 d5 05 00 00 24 02 00 00 d5 05 00 00 24 02 00 00 d5 05 00 00
24 02 00 00 d5 05 00 00 23 02 00 00 d5 05 00 00 23 02 00 00 d5 05 00 00 23 02 00 00 ...

Comment: @Ziggi typecasting a pointer to such raw data to `POINT*` works fine for me,  in 32bit at least. Are you compiling for 64bit, by chance? Allocating an array and filling it in a loop also works fine for me. What do you see happen in your code that is different than you are expecting?

Comment: How can I check if `reinterpret_cast`  works fine with:
`void *memory = (pairs + 0x01719F0F6B + 72);
Polyline(hdc, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(memory), numPairs);`
I am compiling for 64bit.

Comment: @Ziggi assign the result of `reinterpret_cast` to a `POINT*` variable first, then inspect the memory using that pointer. `POINT *points = reinterpret_cast<POINTS*>(memory);`

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` works well. I found an error in recalculating x, y points (LAT, LON) to screen coordinates. Additionally I stored points as y, x instead of x, y. The Polyline couldn't  work correctly. When I fixed problems Polyline works fine now. Thank you especially to Remy Lebeau for his help.